# JOIN and UPDATE a MySQL record with an ID from another table?

Tags: mysql, database, updates

```
    AdminTable
    ----------------------------
    ID | Start Date | LoginID
    ----------------------------
    3  | 10/11      | 28
    4  | 12/12      | 89
    5  | 13/13      | 74
    ----------------------------

    LoginTable:
    -------------------------------
    ID | Email              | Name
    -------------------------------
    28 |   b@gmail.com      | Bob
    89 |   j@gmail.com      | James
    74 |   f@gmail.com      | Bimmy
    ---------------------
```

I want to make an update to the Login table, and change Bimmy to Jimmy. But the only value I have is the user's AdminTableID.

To reiterate: 
Jimmy's Admin Table ID 5. 
I need to find some way to use this ID (5) and match it to his record in the LoginTable where 5 joins to 74 and gives me access to that row.

I want to do something like:
`UPDATE LoginTable AS L SET L.Name = 'Jimmy' WHERE AdminTable.ID = 5`

Any one know how to make this join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE LoginTable 
LEFT JOIN AdminTable ON IFNULL(LoginTable.AdminID,0) = IFNULL(AdminTable.ID,0)
SET name="Jimmy" WHERE AdminTable.ID=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below query will solve this,

```
UPDATE LoginTable
INNER JOIN
AdminTable ON IFNULL(LoginTable.AdminID,0) = IFNULL(AdminTable.ID,0)
SET Name = 'Jimmy' 
WHERE Name = 'Bimmy'
```

Thanks

Comment: What about the cases where the columns are null and you want to update the record to fill it in?

Comment: For that you can use FULL OUTER JOIN instead of inner join

Comment: Eh, MySQL has added FULL OUTER JOIN functionality?

Comment: @renatam23 where which columns are NULL exactly? Can you update the question with an example of this?